# while function with the in operator not working

Tags: python

```
gone = []
turn = 0
def play(XO,player):
 while 0 == 0:
  num = input("\n"+player+" enter an available number where you want to put an '"+XO+"'.\n > ")
  while ((str(num).isdigit() == False) or ((int(num) <= 9 and int(num) >= 1) == False)) or (num in gone):
   num = input("\nValue was not an available number.\n"+player+" enter an available number where you want to put an '"+XO+"'.\n > ")
```

So, in the second while loop I'm having a problem. You see the (num in gone) part? I'm trying to make it so if num is found in the gone list then it will be true, but it isn't working. Instead it passes through it.

I've tested to see if (not num in gone) applies the opposite effect, and it does!

If you need to see my entire code I can post it... btw this is for a Tic-Tac-Toe program I am making.

Comment: It's not easy to analyze the code with that identation. I'd recommend using 4 spaces which is the default for python. On the other hand, you have a `0 == 0` as condition in a while loop. That loop will run forever!

Comment: Yep! Its meant to run forever, the loop can break. But only when a correct number is entered. Edit: sorry about the indentations, this is my first time posting on this site... and it appears some people dont like that (not saying thats you!!)?

Comment: Use ``while True``, that way it doesn't confuse people later. It looks like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting too much logic in one condition. Splitting it up will help you a lot.

Try something like this:

```
gone = []
turn = 0
def play(XO, player):
    while True:
        num = input(
            f"\n{player} enter an available number "
            f"where you want to put an '{XO}'.\n > "
        )

        try:
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number, try again")
            continue

        if num < 1 or num > 9:
            print("Number not in correct range, try again")
            continue

        if num in gone:
            print("Number already gone, try again")
            continue

        gone.append(num)
        turn += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However... it doesnt seem to work when i put it in?